# Find the backslash character in a complex pattern

Tags: regex, vba

I am relatively, no very, new to RegEx.  I have had some success by reading many question and answers here solving my task, but I am stuck on one point.

How to find the backslash `"\"` in a complex pattern.  I am trying to convert any and all date patterns in a string to a specific format.  The only issue I am having is dates in this format `5/22/2016` (or any variation of that using the backslash) aren't being found.

My group for separators is `( |-|/|\\)` as I understand the `"\\"` is required to find a literal `"\"`

I have also tried `( |-|/|c92)` and `( |-|/|\\\\)` but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for any suggestions or ideas.

```
Sub TestRegExDates()
  Dim strIn As String
  Dim lngIndex As Long
  Dim arrDates(1) As String
  'Goal -Convert any valid date found in a string to format MMMM, dd, yyyy"
  arrDates(0) = "21 May 2016 * December 01, 16 * JAN-4-2016"
  arrDates(1) = "5/21/2016 * 12/01/2016 * 1-4-2016 * 5\25\2016"

  'It works well with dates where the month is spelled out.
'  strIn = arrDates(0)
'  strIn = fcnRegExDates(strIn, "((\b\d{4})|\bJan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|\b0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])" _
'                             & "( |-|/|\\)(\bJan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|\b0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(, |\s|-|/|\\)(\b\d{4}\b|\b\d{2}\b)")
'  MsgBox strIn
  'Issue. 'It is close with numerical dates only except when "/" is used as the separator.  I've used the "//" but it doesn't work in this case.
  strIn = arrDates(1)
  strIn = fcnRegExDates(strIn, "((\b\d{4})|\bJan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|\b0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])" _
                             & "( |-|/|\\)(\bJan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|\b0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(, |\s|-|/|\\)(\b\d{4}\b|\b\d{2}\b)")
  MsgBox strIn
  'Work around.  Replace backslashes with forward slashes
  strIn = Replace(arrDates(1), "\", "/")
  strIn = fcnRegExDates(strIn, "((\b\d{4})|\bJan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|\b0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])" _
                             & "( |-|/)(\bJan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?|\b0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(, |\s|-|/)(\b\d{4}\b|\b\d{2}\b)")
  MsgBox strIn
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub

Function fcnRegExDates(strIn As String, strPattern As String, Optional strDateFormat As String = "MMMM dd, yyyy")
  Dim oRegEx As Object
  Dim oMatchCollection As Object
  Dim oMatch As Object
  Dim lngIndex As Long

  Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  oRegEx.Global = True
  With oRegEx
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = strPattern
    On Error GoTo Err_RegEx
    If .Test(strIn) Then
      Set oMatchCollection = .Execute(strIn)
      fcnRegExDates = strIn
      For Each oMatch In oMatchCollection
        If IsDate(oMatch) Then
          fcnRegExDates = (Replace(fcnRegExDates, oMatch, Format(oMatch, strDateFormat)))
        End If
      Next
    Else
      fcnRegExDates = strIn
    End If
  End With
lbl_Exit:
  Set oRegEx = Nothing
  On Error GoTo 0
  Exit Function
Err_RegEx:
  MsgBox "Invalid match pattern"
  fcnRegExDates = strIn
  Resume lbl_Exit:
End Function
```

Comment: Jan,  thanks.  When I saw what I had posted, I immediately went back to try to clean up the disaster but you already did it.

Comment: Well, `( |-|/|\\)` = `([ \\/-])`, and if you do not need to back reference the captured value, you can remove the parentheses. Also (?:e)? =e?

Comment: Dave/Jan,

I tried both your suggestions and it simply won't work for me.  I even dumbed it down to:

 strIn = "05/25/2016"
  strIn = fcnRegExDates(strIn, "05/25/2016")
  MsgBox strIn 'Works
  strIn = "05\25\2016"
  strIn = fcnRegExDates(strIn, "05\\25\\2016") 'Doesn't work
  MsgBox strIn

Answer (score 0):

Tested with 
[RegEx101](https://regex101.com)

Set the RegEx pattern to be:

```
[0-1]{0,1}[0-9]{1}\/[0-3]{0,1}[0-9]\/[0-9]{4}
```

Although you can be more specific with the year if you need to restrict it (example expects 4 numeric digits for the year (0000-9999)

Comment: Dave/Jan,

I tried both your suggestions and it simply won't work for me.  I even dumbed it down to:

 strIn = "05/25/2016"
 strIn = fcnRegExDates(strIn, "05/25/2016")
 MsgBox strIn 'Works
 strIn = "05\25\2016"
 strIn = fcnRegExDates(strIn, "05\\25\\2016") 'Doesn't work
 MsgBox strIn

I don't know what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: I realize that comment looks awful but I didn't see a way to reply and be able to format the code.

Comment: Dave/Jan,

I feel like an idiot.  The issue is not that \\ was not finding a backslash.  The issue is the IsDate function does not recognize 5\16\2016 as a date.  Thanks for you tips in streamlining the pattern.  Sorry for wasting your time.